# Change value of a variable passing through a class is possible?

Tags: angular, typescript

Change value of a variable passing through a class is possible?

Do not work with global variable this.status and also does not work with local variable

I need to change the status right after the execute "appendTo"

the result of both is undefined.

```
        let status;
        const client = new Myclass();
        client.add(url, result => {
            this.status = false;
            result.files.appendTo('#div');

            status = false
        });

        console.log(status)
        console.log(this.status)
```

Comment: Hi, Just to demonstrate the two forms I tried to solve, but neither served. I just need a solution. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let status;
    var me=this;
    const client = new Myclass();
    client.add(url, result => {
        me.status = false;
        result.files.appendTo('#div');
    });

    console.log(status)
    console.log(this.status)
```

Comment: Hi, the status does not change. Now it's empty. Does not show "false"

Comment: hello Bro 
you can pass value to class by reference

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve with "element.innerHTML"